# Setting up an alias for SSH command in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ssh, powershell, alias

In Windows PowerShell:

`>ssh -i \Path\To\key.pem user@server.com` Works like a champ.

`>Set-alias sshalias "ssh -i \Path\To\key.pem user@server.com"` saves the alias with no errors.

`>sshalias` ***returns the following error:***

`sshalias : The module 'ssh -i ' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module ssh -i '.`

`At line:1 char:1`
`+ sshalias`

`+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ssh -i \Path\To\Key.pem user@server.com:String) [], CommandNotFoundException`

```
`+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule`
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to execute that whole string as a command. The command is `ssh`, then there are parameters after it. (That is, there is not an executable or script on your system named "`ssh -i \Path\To\Key.pem "user@server.com"`".)

The solution is to execute the command properly:

```
ssh -i \Path\To\Key.pem "user@server.com"
```

But a PowerShell alias cannot, by definition, have any parameters.

The workaround is to use a function instead:

```
function sshalias { ssh -i \Path\To\Key.pem "user@server.com" }
```

Comment: I'd suggest using an [approved PowerShell verb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7.1#common-verbs), like "**Enter**-ServerDotCom" instead which can then be used by typing `e-s` and tapping TAB.

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell does not permit an alias to include parameters to the command. Instead, to wrap specific parameters for a command into the 'alias', use a function:

```
function sshalias {
    ssh -i \Path\To\key.pem user@server.com
}
```

You might need to quote or escape some of the parameters; I don't use ssh, and I've had inconsistent results with other legacy commands.